# How to add a column in a dask dataframe contains the mean of the values of one column based on the similarity of the values in other columns

Tags: python, dataframe, mean, aggregation, dask

I have a very big CSV file which has been imported in Python as a dask dataframe. I make a small dataframe to explain my question.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv("name and path of the file.csv")
df.head()
```

output:

```
 +----+----+----+----+
 |col1|col2|col3|col4|
 +----+----+----+----+
 |  A |2001|  2 |  5 |
 +----+----+----+----+
 |  A |2001|  2 |  4 |
 +----+----+----+----+
 |  A |2001|  3 |  6 |
 +----+----+----+----+
 |  A |2002|  4 |  5 |
 +----+----+----+----+
 |  B |2001|  2 |  9 |
 +----+----+----+----+
 |  B |2001|  2 |  4 |
 +----+----+----+----+
 |  B |2001|  2 |  3 |
 +----+----+----+----+
 |  B |2001|  3 | 95 |
 +----+----+----+----+
```

I want to add another column `col3_mean` which contains mean of the `col3` if the corresponds values in `col1` are the same.

```
 +----+----+----+----+---------+
 |col1|col2|col3|col4|col3_mean|
 +----+----+----+----+---------+
 |  A |2001|  2 |  5 |   2.75  |
 +----+----+----+----+---------+
 |  A |2001|  2 |  4 |   2.75  |
 +----+----+----+----+---------+
 |  A |2001|  3 |  6 |   2.75  |
 +----+----+----+----+---------+
 |  A |2002|  4 |  5 |   2.75  |
 +----+----+----+----+---------+
 |  B |2001|  2 |  9 |   2.25  |
 +----+----+----+----+---------+
 |  B |2001|  2 |  4 |   2.25  |
 +----+----+----+----+---------+
 |  B |2001|  2 |  3 |   2.25  |
 +----+----+----+----+---------+
 |  B |2001|  3 | 95 |   2.25  |
 +----+----+----+----+---------+
```

I know for this task in `pandas`, we can use:

```
df['col3_mean'] = df.groupby(['col1'])['col3'].transform('mean')
```

I used the following codes in dask but it returns `Nan` value for `col3_mean`

```
df['col3_mean'] = df.groupby(df.col1).col3.mean()
```

I also used `df['index'] = df.groupby(df.lable).col3.mean().collect()` which does not work. Also the following line only returns a `pandas.core.series.Series`

```
df.groupby(df.col1).col3.mean().collect()
```

Answer (score 1):

After posting my question, I could figure out the answer:

```
s = df.groupby(df.col1).col3.mean().compute()
#s is pandas series
df['col3_mean'] = df['col1'].map(s)
```

However, it does not work for my large dataframe. It runs forever and I have to restart my computer.

Please let me know if you have any alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

The following codes work for my big data

```
agg = df.groupby(['lable']).open_cap.aggregate(["mean"])
agg.columns = ['col3_mean']
df = df.merge(agg.reset_index(), on="lable", how="left")
```

Please add your answer to this question too if you have any.